# Run-Android Unexpected Token '*'

Tags: android, react-native

I've both ejected an app I am working on, and created a new app through `react-native init` and for both apps, whenever I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error.

[image]

Does anyone know what the issue might be?  I am developing on a mac.

Comment: This is happening in a clean build?

Comment: @WillRu Yes, I've run `./gradlew clean`

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I know maybe it's not a proper solution, but it might be helpful to have some light on this. After being annoyed with this exact problem for hours, I figured out that if you enable remote debugging, in my case loads the app successfully.

Very weird! Any ideas?

Comment: @mguellsegarra thsi does fix it.. any idea on how to really fix it?

Comment: @reidisaki look at my answer below and tell me if is your case too ;)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I finally know what was going wrong. I was using the new exponentiation operator (**), but for some reason, doesn't work well with react-native and Android. Check if you're using it and replace it with classic `Math.pow()`. Worked for me.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8290#issuecomment-315491051

Comment: haha i did look at your post but i think its something else going on with my build. What i find interesting is that if i have debugging on i don't see this issue.  Thanks man!

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver!!

Comment: just changed it because of eslint, great find!